# Using console.readline during console.writeline

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net I am trying to write a program using the console where the console writes the line 'number of cars:', and the console assigns the number inputed after the colon to a variable. Is there a way to get the console to read a value within a line that was written. i.e can you use console.readline() within console.writeline()?

Comment: I think you want to use `Console.Write` instead of `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: The user wouldn't be writing the input *within* the text that was shown to them.  They'd be writing the input *after* that text.  First write to the console, then read from the console.  The two don't mix.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `Console.Write` and then `Console.ReadLine` for this.

For example:

```
Console.Write("Number of cars: ")
Dim cars As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), cars) Then
  ' Do something interesting
  Console.WriteLine("{0} cars, eh?", cars)
Else
  Console.WriteLine("Couldn't tell how many cars!")
End If
```

Output will be something like this:

```
Number of cars: 3
3 cars, eh?
```

Comment: ...perhaps this is a comment?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob: No? This is how to do what the OP wants done, modulo their misunderstandings of .NET. If that's not an answer I'm not sure what is.

Comment: @NathanTuggy A small code example and a sample of output would make this into a better answer ;)

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Hmm, fair enough. Done.